# Lost Windows 7 when loading Ubuntu

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu as a dual boot with Windows 7 following the step on the installation.  Ubuntu works fine, and Windows 7 appears as an option on the boot menu, but when selected, hangs.
I was concerned to see files from my windows installation appearing in a Device called OS in the file manager.
Have I lost everything? or is there some way back?

Comment: How do you installed Ubuntu? Which version of Ubuntu do you have? Can you say which files are in the root folder of the OS device? *Edit:* in some cases, it can be solved using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Using the **Recommended repair** option should solve anything related with GRUB fails.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The version is 12.04 LTS.  The OS device seems to have all the files and directories of my windows C:\ directory.

Comment: OK, it may be a problem of GRUB, the Ubuntu loader. Let me check...

Comment: Check this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: This only works if you installed it booting from the CD instead of Windows!

Comment: I did install booting from the CD - trying it now.  Thanks!

Comment: Tried it, but no luck.  I have sent the URL that the utility gave me to boot repair.

Comment: OK... then I don't know what can you do :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have messed up the MBR of windows. Just try to put a window DVD or USB(window setup on it) and start a system repair and fix the MBR of windows by the command at system repair:

```
c:\>bootrec /fixmbr
```

this command also worked for me to get back windows:

```
c:\>bootrec /fixboot
```

After that, you have to reinstall the grub loader. Just try a live CD of ubuntu and open terminal and write:

```
mount /dev/your_boot_partiton /boot
grub-install --root-directory /boot /dev/hda
```

Now You can dual boot both operating system properly. For me it worked well.
*EDIT:*
You can view your windows partitions on linux as `fdisk-l` and listing out the ntfs partitions. 
On windows, similar can be achieved by

```
x:\>diskpart.exe
diskpart>select disk 0
diskpart>list volume
```

and from there you can come up to know the partition of the window

Comment: Thanks.  I have a problem with the first part.  The windows setup was on a hidden partition, and I wasn't given a CD.  Can you tell me how to access the partitions?

Comment: Hidden? in which sense the partition is hidden? I mean from which operating system are you accessing the partitions?

Comment: From Windows - not sure of the details. I'm trying to get hold of a Windows DVD so I can follow your advice.

Comment: Drat - didn't work.
I got hold of a Windows Recovery disc and followed your first 2 steps - both reporting success.
The next step (on Ubuntu) had problems with /dev/hda.
However I used Boot-Repair to fix grub instead (http://paste.ubuntu.com/963000) and now have to entries for Windows 7 (on /dev/sda2 & /dev/sda3) neither of which work.  Both hang after printing 8 dashes with a line of coloured dots along the top of the screen.  Any additional help very welcome.